# iOS 7 UIBarButtonItem set font not worked when it is highlighted

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

I use these function to change navigation bar item font and color, it worked fine before iOS 7, but in iOS 7, when show an alert in this view controller, the left navigation item changed it's color to blue and font is bigger. After search, I can use

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

to change color to blue.

But how to change font?

Comment: change font ? do you mean change font size or font face ? You didn't set `UIControlStateHighlighted` text state.

Comment: change font size, set UIControlStateHighlighted text state also not work.

Comment: For me also the same kind of is not working over iOS7, where I am updating font color for all the various states. It shows only default dark grey color for disable state, even though I have changed it to some other value.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your 'titleAttributes' dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *titleAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0], UITextAttributeFont,  nil];
```